# three.js Blender export, object path&rotation

Tags: rotation, three.js, blender

If someone could help me solve a problem. I wantto get a JSON with animation, traveling at a certain path.

```
var up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
var pt,radians,tangent;
var axis = new THREE.Vector3();

var pot = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
        new THREE.Vector3(640,360,510),
        new THREE.Vector3(650,360,520),
        new THREE.Vector3(0,20,0)]);
....
pt = pot.getPoint(stevec);
meshK.position.set(pt.x,pt.y,pt.z);
tangent=pot.getTangent(stevec).normalize();
axis.crossVectors(up,tangent).normalize();
radians=Math.acos(up.dot(tangent));
meshK.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis,radians);
//meshK.eulerOrder='ZYX';
stevec+=0.001;
```

- I'm trying to get a plane like object to fly a certain path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the initial rotation after quaternion is set. I also had to export the JSON with flipYZ flag.